# Using Min function in MS access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Below is sql query that i am have created in ms access query. i am trying to use a sub-query to get the minimum outcome date for each young person but i get the error message "you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified aggregate function"

I am aware that there are other ways to produce the data I want but just wanted to know if it is possible to  use sub-query to do this

I am aware that there are other ways to produce the data I want but just wanted to know if it is possible to  use sub-query to do this

```
SELECT A.YPID, A.min_out_date
FROM (SELECT  YP.YPID, min(Outcomes.Outcome_Date) AS [min_out_date] 
FROM YP INNER JOIN Outcomes ON YP.YPID=Outcomes.YPID)  AS A
GROUP BY A.YPID, A.min_out_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `JOIN` at all:

```
SELECT o.YPID, MIN(o.Outcome_Date) as min_out_date
FROM Outcomes as o
GROUP BY o.YPID;
```

All the information needed in the result set is in `Outcomes`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
SELECT A.YPID, min(A.min_out_date) as mindate
FROM 
(
SELECT  YP.YPID, Outcomes.Outcome_Date AS [min_out_date] 
FROM YP INNER JOIN Outcomes ON YP.YPID=Outcomes.YPID
)  AS A
GROUP BY A.YPID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a subquery (which I don't think is necessary here), you would just group by in the subquery:

```
SELECT A.YPID, A.min_out_date FROM (SELECT  YP.YPID, min(Outcomes.Outcome_Date) AS [min_out_date] FROM YP INNER JOIN Outcomes ON YP.YPID=Outcomes.YPID group by YP.YPID) AS A;
```